# Strong synergy between autoboxing and varargs

Tags: java, autoboxing, java-5

As said in the java documentation i.e. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html,
There is a **strong synergy between *autoboxing* and varargs**, which is illustrated in the following program using reflection:

```
    // Simple test framework
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int passed = 0;
        int failed = 0;
        for (String className : args) {
            try {
                Class c = Class.forName(className);
                c.getMethod("test").invoke(c.newInstance());
                passed++;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.printf("%s failed: %s%n", className, ex);
                failed++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("passed=%d; failed=%d%n", passed, failed);
    }
}
```

But I didn't understood how/where those **getMethod** & **invoke** methods are using the autoboxing concept here?

**NOTE:** I know these 2 methods are vararg based methods but where is autobaoxing using here?

Comment: Looks like bogus documentation to me... (It's still there in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html btw.)

Comment: The only thing i can think of: I assume that printf only accepts reference types as arguments. Autoboxing would allow you to use primitive types as well (so printf("whatever ..." , 5) works with autoboxing.

Comment: Hey! EddyG, Thank you very much for the clarification. I understood that "printf" is a varargs method with Objects only but still working with primitives due to autoboxing. Hence strong synergy between autoboxing and varargs.

Comment: "printf" is clear because there is a possibility to pass the primitives which is   taking care by autoboxing -> varargs.  But how the "getMethod" & "invoke" methods are using the autoboxing because there is no possible of passing primitives for those methods?